# How to tunnel DDNS domain with SSL through a VPS to IPv6 host (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: ssl, ipv6, https, tunnel, dynamic-dns

I am working on reaching my Raspberry Pi, which is running behind an IPv6 router, with HTTPS working. I am very confused, because HTTP is working at the moment.

So my setup looks like this:

- **mydns.ddnshost.com** targets my VPS on IPv4
- VPS is configured with 6tunnel to **tunnel port 80 and port 443** to my Raspberry Pis IPv6:
  `6tunnel 80 IPv6-address 80` && `6tunnel 443 IPv6-address 443`
- RPi runs DietPi (*LLMP + owncloud + CertBot for SSL certificate*)
- CertBot / LetsEncrypt domain is set to **mydns.ddnshost.com**
- On our router the RPi should be publicly reachable on all ports with all protocolls ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zTYe.jpg))

On setting up the SSL certificate `dietpi-letsencrypt` I use my ddns domain **mydns.ddnshost.com**. And on the local network HTTPS connection to the RPi works, as well.

While normal HTTP calls succeed and I can reach my owncloud installation from the outside, HTTPS calls fail. I am no expert in webhosting and pretty new to using tunnels. In the past I was able to set up a working HTTPS owncloud installation, by using a paid portmapping service. But since I have this VPS running today, I would like to do my own IPv6 mapping / tunneling to my RPi.

Am I missing something here? Or what configuration may block the HTTPS call to succeed? I would be happy to read your opinions and help.

Greetings

Comment: Please describe in much greater detail how the HTTPS calls "fail".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late response, but I had a busy week.

I have redone the setup today and got it working now. One thing, that I noticed and which I may have overcome before is the following:

On the old DietPi installation `dietpi-software` I used [nginx + mariadb + php7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug28x.png)

**BUT:** I did not [change the webserver setting to Nginx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4hBX.png) after.

So my steps to get a working owncloud IPv6 installation and reach it via DDNS and IPv6 tunnel were most likely:

1. On DietPi: Install LEMP as Webserver stack
2. On DietPi: Change `Webserver Preference` to Nginx
3. On DietPi: Install Owncloud
4. On DietPi: In `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` set root to `/var/www/owncloud`
5. On Client: Test if I reach my Raspberry Pis OwnCloud via LAN
6. On VPS: `6tunnel 80 IPV6 80`
7. On Client: Test if I reach my RaspberryPis OwnCloud via VPS-IPv4
8. On DDNS: Set up ddns provider (I used noip.com) to redirect to my VPS-IPv4
9. On DietPi: Install CertBot
10. On DietPi: Run `dietpi-letsencrypt` and use my ddns domain (from noip.com)
11. On VPS: `6tunnel 443 RaspberryPi-IPv6 443`

In addition it might be worth to know, that on my IPv6 router I forwarded all protocols  and ports to my raspi.

Now it works for me. :))